# What's the pythonic way of generating a range of chars?

Tags: python

In other languages, I would use a construct like this:

```
a..z
```

I couldn't come up with a better solution than this:

```
[chr(x) for x in range(ord("a"), ord("z") + 1)]
```

Is there a shorter, more readable way of building such a list ?

Comment: In an effort to dissuade people from answering with it, I'm going to mention [`string.lowercase`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.lowercase) in a comment, but it only works if you want the whole alphabet (**Edit**: ...sigh)

Comment: Yes, _string.lowercase_ could be used, it's also a readable solution, but it only works if you want the whole alphabet. I really wish I could do something like _range("a","c")_

Comment: I think this solution is actually a nice one. But as it is right now, it just goes from `a` to `y`, `ord('z') + 1` should solve the problem

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily great if you want to do something other than a to z, but you can do this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
for c in ascii_lowercase:
    print c
```

Comment: Pretty great for other ranges than `a..z`, because you can easily take a slice of `ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: @larsmans Easily...how? Other than manually converting the end characters to offsets in your head, which kind of defeats the point

Answer (score 1):

My way is similar to yours but you can use `map` and  create an arbitrary function like this

```
>>> def generate_list(char1,char2):
...      myl = map(chr, range(ord(char1),ord(char2)+1))
...      print myl
...
>>> generate_list("a","d")
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your list-comprehension, but maybe you want to try:

```
from string import lowercase
print lowercase
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
print list(lowercase)
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

As noted by julio.alegria and Nathan Binkert `lowercase` is a string of a all lower-case letters and Python strings are iterables.

If you require subsets of the alphabet, there are nice and Pythonic ways to do this:

```
print lowercase.find('f')
  5
print lowercase[5,9]
  fghij
print filter(lambda c: ord('f') <= ord(c) <= ord('j'), lowercase)
  fghij
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def charRange(start, end):
    offset = ord('a')
    return ascii_lowercase[ord(start)-offset:ord(end)-offset+1]

charRange('a', 'f')
> 'abcdef'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the list comprehension with a `map(chr,range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1))` call, but that's perhaps not what you're really asking. The example you show, however, is more appropriately imported; it is available as a string in `string.lowercase`.

Assuming letters match up with ordinals may be a mistake, considering letters like ß and æ, which may be sorted differently depending on locales (i.e. åäö are last in the alphabet for Swedish, but ä and ö are variants of a and o in German). That's why we have functions like unicode.islower() and locale.strcoll().

Answer (score 0):

As noted elsewhere, the letters 'a' through 'z' are already in [string.lowercase](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.lowercase).  Thus you can just take a slice of that.

```
import string
def create_letter_list(start_char, end_char):
    return string.lowercase[ord(start_char) - ord('a'): ord(end_char) - ord('a') + 1]

letter_list = create_letter_list('g', 'n')
 print letter_list
```

Output:

> ghijklmn

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def random_chars(size=10, chrs=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chrs) for x in range(size))
```

Comment: Not sure why you think a selection of random letters is the desired result.